# Is there any way to insert image logo/ Text in before saving to_html in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am saving pandas output as to_html()

Is there any way to integrate the logo/Text at the top of the html page before saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) returns a string with the html if the first parameter `buf` is `None`. You can than prepend your image or text html to this string and then write this result string to a file.

```
output = '<img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo"><br><b>some text</b><br>' + df.to_html()
with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```